# Hippie doesn't use yasnippet and fallback to emmet with emacs-lisp-mode

Tags: hooks, yasnippet, hippie-expand, emmet

I use `hippie-expand` with [`emmet`](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode) and [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet).

```el
(use-package emmet-mode
  :init
  (add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
  (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode)
  :config (unbind-key "<C-return>" emmet-mode-keymap))

(use-package hippie-exp
  :bind ("<C-return>" . hippie-expand)
  :config
  (setq-default
   hippie-expand-try-functions-list '(yas-hippie-try-expand emmet-expand-line)))

(use-package yasnippet
  :init
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode 'yas-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
  :config (yas-reload-all))
```

1. It works fine with `js-mode`, `org-mode` and with `html-mode`. But with `emacs-lisp-mode` and with `lisp-interaction-mode`, `hippie-expand` always delegate completion to `emmet-expand-line`.
2. Emmet completion is still available in non-emmet'ified buffers after an emmet'ified one has been opened (`css-mode-hook` and `sgml-mode-hook`). Is the right way to fix this to change `hippie-expand-try-functions-list` on `prog-mode-hook` depending on the current major mode?

How can I setup `hippie-expand` with `emmet` and `yasnippet` to fix these 2 issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine with `js-mode`, `org-mode` and with `html-mode`. But with `emacs-lisp-mode` and with `lisp-interaction-mode`, `hippie-expand` always delegate completion to `emmet-expand-line`.

It's a typo in your config: you're adding to `emacs-lisp-mode` instead of `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`.

> Emmet completion is still available in non-emmet'ified buffers after an emmet'ified one has been opened (`css-mode-hook` and `sgml-mode-hook`). Is the right way to fix this to change `hippie-expand-try-functions-list` on `prog-mode-hook` depending on the current major mode?

That should work.  Alternatively you could use a function that only operates when `emmet-mode` is enabled:

```el
(defun emmet-hippie-try-expand-line (args)
  (interactive "P")
  (when emmet-mode
    (emmet-exand-line args)))
(setq-default hippie-expand-try-functions-list
              '(yas-hippie-try-expand
                emmet-hippie-try-expand-line))
```